# How to add an application to LXQt panel

Tags: lubuntu, lxqt

In Lubuntu 20.04 with LXQt environment, I am trying to pin my Spotify application icon to the Quicklaunch bar on the panel. However, I can seem to only delete the current icons, not add any... How can I do this. Right clicking Spotify doesn't seem to give me an option to add it to quicklaunch. Thanks.

Comment: Saw your comment below. Something is wrong with your system - as their answer is the correct one. When testing 20.04, I can easily drag kcalc to the system tray. I grabbed the Spotify snap and I can easily move that to the tray. Try dropping the icon on top of an existing icon. It can take a few tries. You did mention that you got some sort of error message with kcalc. Can you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1312488/edit) your post to include the error and any other relevant information?

Comment: Try reading the manual page on it - https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/5/5.1/lxqt-panel.html?highlight=quicklaunch   (*I've written an answer for this already on this site, but cannot find it, but it was mostly taken from the manual with some comments that it's a little exact*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

click the bird button (Left Bottom) Left click hold and drag a application (spotify icon) to the Quick Launch.

Comment: I am able to drag applications to the quicklaunch but not able to actually place them there (red x icon appears). There is even an error message from lxqt when trying to add Kcalc to the quicklaunch menu from the File Manager. Your answer is correct according to lxqt docs, I guess its just a broken feature.

Comment: Not from file manager, click the bird button (Left  Bottom) and drag a application from there. Editing first to include the same.

Comment: I see now, thank you very much, it worked perfectly